# An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary for the product type 'Application' in xcode version 10.2

Tags: ios, webrtc

I have compile webrtc ios source code ,then I used the command:

```
gn gen out/ios --args='target_os="ios" target_cpu="arm64"' --ide=xcode
```

then I open the workspace with Xcode.

but when I compile the code, Xcode gives me this error below.

An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary for the product type 'Application'. (in target 'AppRTCMobile')

[image]

my Xcode version is 10.2, the latest version.

I really don't know how did this happen,can anyone can help me?

my code sign setting is:

[image]

everything looks ok.

Comment: Check your code signing settings. Are you using the correct team and profile for the targets ?

Comment: Team: kai zhang  Signing Certiticate iPhone Developer :........, this account is ok for build other programs.

Comment: There is no info.plist associated in your project. Click on that choose info.plist file and the select the one for that project.

Comment: thanks ,but unfortunately，it is not working.

Comment: it's my mistake,i should select the target AppRTCMobile,and the select info.plist,thanks,it's help me.

Answer (score 49):

I added `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO` as an additional parameter and that fixed this issue for me.

- **Steps**: `Xcode`->`Project`->`{yourProjectName}`->`Build Settings`->add `User-Defined` para: `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO`

  - [image]
- **Note**

  - if still error, do multiple try:

    - `Xcode`->`Product`->`Clean Build Folders`
    - `Xcode`->`Product`->`Clean All Issues`

Comment: Mine was missing a `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY`, but your fix found me mine!

Answer (score 17):

I needed to to turn OFF `Automatic manage signing` and turn it ON afterwards. It seems like Xcode did fix some inconsistency by that action.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this error in Xcode 12.2b when building to run on a device, but I had not set signing to Automatic, or selected profiles, etc.

Basically I was running and testing on the simulator, then plugged in a device for testing and forgot to change any signing settings.

Perhaps this error is new to Xcode 12.x for that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using CocoaPods check your `project.pbxproj` for `(null)` references, there's an issue that make `BuildFile` references to become `(null)`

Even if you have the identity correctly defined it may be "empty" because of [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/574)

Try, as suggested:

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur when an Xcode project is **generated** (rather than built from within xcode), and the generated output project is unexpectedly in release mode.

I was working on a Godot project and got the above error which led me to this post.  The error is not WebRTC or Godot specific.

1. If you only want to **debug** the project for now on a device, and don't need release builds yet, switch to a debug scheme using the scheme switcher (1)
2. If the generator didn't create a debug scheme, (which is the case for me for my issue) you can add one via New Scheme (2)
3. At first I could not work out why it was complaining about "empty identity" (this refers to the `Team` drop down) when as per the screen shot I had this value set.  I had the project view filter settings on Debug (as per the screenshot (3) so the Release settings (where Team was set to "None") were not showing up. Change this to `All` to see if that is where the `None` in the error is coming from for you.

[image]

Debug builds only require a basic signing setup.  If you still have issues with Release builds when it comes time for that, you may need to clear out certificates & provisioning profiles from your Derived Data, Apple Developer portal and Keychain.

[Release build certificates are hard to manage & replace](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659545) so be careful with randomly generating & deleting them.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The problem has been fixed, it's my mistake.

Select the target, then choose info.plist and select the one for your project.