# How to fix code signing error in Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, codesign, code-signing-entitlements

I keep getting this error. I tried everything.

Code Signing Warning: "OSCSender - App" isn't code signed but requires entitlements. It is not possible to add entitlements to a binary without signing it.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 13.2'

- [Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0' - StickerPackExtension requires a development team error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic)
- [An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary for the product type 'Application' in xcode version 10.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55489697/an-empty-identity-is-not-valid-when-signing-a-binary-for-the-product-type-appli)

I also tried to switch from the new build system to legacy. I have turned on/off automatic signing. 
I deleted all provisioning profiles, certificates and my account from Xcode. still the same problem!

I tried to turn off code signing from the .plist but it doesn't let me, even when I run as admin.

- Catalina 10.15.2
- Xcode Version 11.3

Answer (score 3):

It happens when Xcode doesn't recognize your certificate.

It's just a pain in the ass to solve it, there are a lot of possibilities to help you.

But the first thing you should try is removing in the "Window" tab => Organizer, the provisioning that is in your device. Then re-add them (download them again on the apple website). And try to compile again.

By the way, did you check in the Project Info Window the "code signing identity"?